# var require: NodeRequire (id: string) => any – CommonJS module, converted into an ES6 module.ts (80001)

Tags: javascript, gulp, es6-modules

## What is actually correct?

**gulpfile.js**

```js
// Modules & Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
const image = require('gulp-image');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```

> **I get the info from the editor:**
> var require: NodeRequire
>   (id: string) => any
> The file is a CommonJS module, it can be converted into an ES6 module.ts (80001)

**after I go to "quick fix" it converts the lines**

```js
// Modules & Plugins
import { task, src, dest, watch, parallel } from 'gulp';
import image from 'gulp-image';
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```